# GWT - EventBus calling event for object that no longer exists

Tags: events, gwt, event-bus

I ran into this problem in a large program, so I wrote a small sample to test it. I'm hoping someone can explain this to me.

Here's the code:

```
EventBus bus = new SimpleEventBus();

class TestClass {
    TestClass() {
        bus.addHandler(TestEvent.TYPE, new TestHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(TestEvent event) {
                System.out.println("test");
            }

        });
    }
}

class TestEvent extends GwtEvent<TestHandler> {
    public static final GwtEvent.Type<TestHandler> TYPE = new GwtEvent.Type<TestHandler>();

    @Override
    public Type<TestHandler> getAssociatedType() {
        return TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatch(TestHandler handler) {
        handler.onEvent(this);
    }
}

interface TestHandler extends EventHandler {
    void onEvent(TestEvent event);
}
```

After which I do the following:

```
TestClass c1 = new TestClass();
c1 = new TestClass();
bus.fireEvent(new TestEvent());
```

Now by my logic, the output to this should be a single "test"; in fact, it is two "test"s, the handler is called twice. I don't really get why this is; c1 is a single object, so shouldn't the handler only be called once?

Answer (score 1):

You created two instances of `TestClass`, referencing the latter via `c1`. During each instantiation an anonymous handler was added to your single global bus. There are thus two handlers the bus has in its collection and calls when you fire `TestEvent`, hence two "test"s.

Comment: Shouldn't the first `TestClass` be cleaned up by the garbage collector when I remove the reference from it though? Why does that persist?

Comment: The first `TestClass` is still referenced by its anonymous `TestHandler` registered to the bus, so it cannot be GC'd. WBut what matters is actually the `TestHandler`, and you never remove it from the bus, so the bus still knows it, and it won't be GC'd, and will be notified of events.